# When debugging an ASP.NET Application, how to end debug session when Firefox closes?

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio

I am going to set Mozilla Firefox as my default web browser to .net applications. The problem is that the application keep on running mode even I close the browser window. Its not the same with IE.

For certain reasons I have to use Fire Fox instead of IE.

Is there any way to close the application (stop) when the Firefox window is closed (not by explicitly hitting the stop button on the project window)?

### Update

I do agree with all of you but the thing is that happened with IE can't be with any other browser. I am looking for some settings/option so that it will kill the process as soon as the Firefox window is closed.

Comment: Good question.  I always wondered that...

Comment: Great Idea... we should be able to do this to any browser :)

Comment: yes but my basic requirement is with firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure you Web Application project's Start Action to "Start external program", point it to firefox, set command line arguments to your site. E.g.

```
Start external program: C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
Command line arguments: http://localhost:8888/
```

Does this fit your needs?

Comment: I'm not sure whether you are using Web Site Project or Web Application project, so I'll give instructions for both. For Web Site project, righ-click on project, choose Property pages, go to Start options and configure Start action as described in my answer. For Web Application project right-click on project, choose Properties, go to Web and configure Start Action as described in my answer.

Comment: +1 This works for me with Visual Developer Express. VS2008 is presumably the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the built-in web server in VS then you can kill it by right-clicking the icon in the system tray. Not sure if that is what you mean?

Comment: He is debugging and his debugger does not stop automatically when the browser is closed.

Comment: Or just clicking the 'Stop' button (Shift + F5) in Visual Studio.

Comment: @Joel He's trying not to click that button explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

For those who answer this question, please try to have a test with yours vs first, instead of simply answer here. Using your vs and set firefox as your vs default browser, then run it. After you running a webpage, then close the firefox, see your program still running.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to look into extensibility model for VS 2010?

There might be a way to customize launch connection to browser.

Or Possibly Build a FireFox Plug in that interacts with VS the same way IE does.

I really have no idea... just thought i would throw some areas i would start looking into~

Good Luck~