# Web Page not being closed after debugging session is stopped

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

Using Visual Studio 2008 (Tried Team Edition and Professional), I have a web service app, that when I stop debugging the FireFox Browser Tab remains open.

How can I change the behaviour of VS / Firefox to close this window when the debugging is stopped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From what I can tell this is not possible.**

I'd recommend getting in the habit of closing the tab then stopping debugging.

Alternatively, you could select the Local IIS option

Right Click the Project > Web Tab > Servers Section > Select the 'Use Local IIS Web Server' option.

If you have IIS installed it will create a virtual directory for you.  You can rebuild and just navigate to your local url.  Debug if needed or even attach to the w3wp.exe if you want.

This mode is very handy when you're just doing layout stuff as well and you don't care about the code but just want to update markup etc. and refresh quickly.

Related:

[How To Prevent Tab Hell With Visual Studio And FireFox Debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247908/how-to-prevent-tab-hell-with-visual-studio-and-firefox-debugging)

[When Debugging an ASP.NET Application, How to End Debug Session when Firefox Closes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171475/when-debugging-an-asp-net-application-how-to-end-debug-session-when-firefox-clos)

Comment: Thanks, but do you know what exactly the problem is - is it because I am using Firefox?

Comment: @JL yeah, from my experience IE integrates well with visual studio while Firefox just stays open.